# What is "thread local storage" in Python, and why do I need it?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-local

In Python specifically, how do variables get shared between threads?

Although I have used `threading.Thread` before I never really understood or saw examples of how variables got shared.  Are they shared between the main thread and the children or only among the children? When would I need to use thread local storage to avoid this sharing?

I have seen many warnings about synchronizing access to shared data among threads by using locks but I have yet to see a really good example of the problem.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. The question is to do with sharing variables between threads, the title implies that it is specifically about thread local storage

Comment: @Casebash: from the sound of this question, Mike read that TLS is necessary to avoid the problems caused by shared data, but was unclear as to which data was shared by default, what it was shared with, and how it became shared. I've adjusted the title to better match the question.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In Python, everything is shared, except for function-local variables (because each function call gets its own set of locals, and threads are always separate function calls.) And even then, only the variables themselves (the names that refer to objects) are local to the function; objects themselves are always global, and anything can refer to them.
The `Thread` object for a particular thread is not a special object in this regard. If you store the `Thread` object somewhere all threads can access (like a global variable) then all threads can access that one `Thread` object. If you want to atomically modify *anything* that another thread has access to, you have to protect it with a lock. And all threads must of course share this very same lock, or it wouldn't be very effective.

If you want actual thread-local storage, that's where `threading.local` comes in. Attributes of `threading.local` are not shared between threads; each thread sees only the attributes it itself placed in there. If you're curious about its implementation, the source is in [_threading_local.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_threading_local.py) in the standard library.

Comment: Can you give more details about the following sentence please?
"If you want to atomically modify anything that you didn't just create in this very same thread, and did not store anywhere another thread can get at it, you have to protect it by a lock."

Comment: @changyuheng: Here is an explanation of what atomic actions are: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psznza/G52CON/lecture4.pdf

Comment: @TomBusby: If there are not any other threads can get at it, why do we need to protect it by a lock, i.e. why do we need to make the process atomic?

Comment: Please can you give a quick example of: "objects themselves are always global, and anything can refer to them". By refer assume you mean read and not assign/append?

Comment: @variable:  I think he means [values have no scope](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_dynamic_typing)

Comment: I didn't understand and I am still looking for a simple example to help understand this line from the answer: "objects themselves are always global, and anything can refer to them"

Comment: @variable in some programming language values are passed by reference, so you can modify variables value in upper scope(in python u can pretend this behavior by ```global``` and ```nonlocal```) some are passed by value(so you can't change the outer scopes value, however, you can access it). but in python, all thing is object and variable are references to objects. you have access to the outer scope object but you can't change it. this is handled by the bonding mechanism. inside and outside the function access the ```id(x)``` which x bound to 5. the return id will be the same.

Answer (score 97):

Consider the following code:

```
#/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep
from random import random
from threading import Thread, local

data = local()

def bar():
    print("I'm called from", data.v)

def foo():
    bar()

class T(Thread):
    def run(self):
        sleep(random())
        data.v = self.getName()   # Thread-1 and Thread-2 accordingly
        sleep(1)
        foo()
```

```
 >> T().start(); T().start()
I'm called from Thread-2
I'm called from Thread-1
```

Here threading.local() is used as a quick and dirty way to pass some data from run() to bar() without changing the interface of foo().

Note that using global variables won't do the trick:

```
#/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep
from random import random
from threading import Thread

def bar():
    global v
    print("I'm called from", v)

def foo():
    bar()

class T(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global v
        sleep(random())
        v = self.getName()   # Thread-1 and Thread-2 accordingly
        sleep(1)
        foo()
```

```
 >> T().start(); T().start()
I'm called from Thread-2
I'm called from Thread-2
```

Meanwhile, if you could afford passing this data through as an argument of foo() - it would be a more elegant and well-designed way:

```
from threading import Thread

def bar(v):
    print("I'm called from", v)

def foo(v):
    bar(v)

class T(Thread):
    def run(self):
        foo(self.getName())
```

But this is not always possible when using third-party or poorly designed code.

Answer (score 29):

You can create thread local storage using `threading.local()`.

```
>>> tls = threading.local()
>>> tls.x = 4 
>>> tls.x
4
```

Data stored to the tls will be unique to each thread which will help ensure that unintentional sharing does not occur.

Comment: threading.local().x - attribute error

Comment: @iperov that's not how you use it. You're supposed to make a variable and assign `threading.local()` to it, and then create subvariables under it using dot notation like in the answer. Under the hood, the class is like a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Just like in every other language, every thread in Python has access to the same variables. There's no distinction between the 'main thread' and child threads.

One difference with Python is that the Global Interpreter Lock means that only one thread can be running Python code at a time. This isn't much help when it comes to synchronising access, however, as all the usual pre-emption issues still apply, and you have to use threading primitives just like in other languages. It does mean you need to reconsider if you were using threads for performance, however.

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning `threading.local()` is not a singleton.

You can use more of them per thread.
It is **not one storage**.

Comment: thus this is regular dotdict() and not a thread local storage at all

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong here. If you know otherwise please expound as this would help explain why one would need to use thread local().

This statement seems off, not wrong: "If you want to atomically modify anything that another thread has access to, you have to protect it with a lock." I think this statement is ->effectively<- right but not entirely accurate. I thought the term "atomic" meant that the Python interpreter created a byte-code chunk that left no room for an interrupt signal to the CPU.

I thought atomic operations are chunks of Python byte code that does not give access to interrupts. Python statements like "running = True" is atomic. You do not need to lock CPU from interrupts in this case (I believe). The Python byte code breakdown is safe from thread interruption.

Python code like "threads_running[5] = True" is not atomic. There are two chunks of Python byte code here; one to de-reference the list() for an object and another byte code chunk to assign a value to an object, in this case a "place" in a list. An interrupt can be raised -->between<- the two byte-code ->chunks<-. That is were bad stuff happens.

How does thread local() relate to "atomic"? This is why the statement seems misdirecting to me. If not can you explain?