# How is `x = 42; x = lambda: x` parsed?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

I was surprised that this assertion fails:

```
x = 42
x = lambda: x
assert x() == 42
```

It seems that `x` ends up recursively referring to itself, so that `x()`, `x()()`, etc. are all functions.

What is the rule used to parse this, and where is this documented?

By the way (not unexpectedly given the above), the original value of `x` has no references left after the lambda definition:

```
class X:
  def __del__(self): print('deleting')

x = X()
x = lambda: x  # 'deleting' is printed here
```

Comment: It is like `def x(): return x`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The variable `x` is created by the first assignment, and rebound with the second assignment.

Since the `x` in the lambda isn't evaluated until the lambda is called, calling it will evaluate to the most recently assigned value.

Note that this is not dynamic scoping - if it were dynamic, the following would print "99", but it prints "<function ...":

```
x = 42
x = lambda: x

def test(f):
  x = 99
  print(f())

test(x)
```

Comment: So this is lexical (=static) scope, correct? Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51604390/336527.

Comment: Note: with `nonlocal x; x = 99`, it *does* print 99.

Comment: Or maybe the example would be easier to understand with `test(lambda: x)`, distinguishing 42 from 99

Answer (score 39):

The first assignment is irrelevant; the `x` in the body of the `lambda` is [bound late](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding):

```
x = lambda: x # no need for a prior assignment
x = lambda: y # notice: no NameError occurs, *until it is called*
```

This is the same reason that [creating lambdas in a loop is tricky](/questions/452610/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-python-lambdas-in-a-list-comprehension-for-loop), and is also used to [make trees with the standard library `defaultdict`](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250):

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
t = tree()
t['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'look ma, no intermediate steps'
```

Answer (score 13):

A lambda is an anonymous function object. Python completely resolves whatever is on the right side of an equation to a single anonymous object and then resolves whatever is on the left side for assignment.

```
x = lambda: x
```

first compiles `lambda: x` into a function object that returns whatever happens to be in `x` at the time it is called. It then rebinds `x` with this function object, deleting whatever object happened to be there before.

Now `x` is a function that returns whatever is in `x`... which is a function that returns whatever is in `x`, etc... So you can write `x()()()()()()` as many times as you want, and still get that orginal `lambda:x` function object.

Python functions have a local namespace but only variables assigned in the function reside there. Since `x` isn't assigned in the `lambda`, it's resolved in the containing scope - that is, the module level "x". An identical piece of code is

```
def x():
    return x
```

Contrast this with

```
def x():
    x = 1
    return x
```

Now, the parameter `x` is a local variable and is unrelated to the global `x`.