# NameError when calling an imported function requiring something defined in the current environment

Tags: python, import, nameerror, scoping, lexical-scope

I have two Python files:

`b.py`:

```py
def buzz():
    foobar = Foobar()
```

`c.py`:

```py
from b import buzz

class Foobar:
    pass

buzz()
```

Running `python c.py` raises:

```
NameError: name 'Foobar' is not defined
```

Looks like there is a basic Python's import mechanism I still don't understand. I would expect that, when `buzz()` is called, it has dynamically access to the environment now containing `Foobar`.

---

Of course (?), if I replace the importation of `buzz` by its definition, it works:

`d.py`:

```py
def buzz():
    foobar = Foobar()

class Foobar:
    pass

buzz()
```

---

**Context.**

This may be an XY-problem. Ultimately, I want to be able to change the behaviour of `buzz` depending on which `Foobar` variant has previously been imported. However, I would be interested in understanding why `b.py` / `c.py` fails.

Comment: Python is lexically scoped ("A function sees its surroundings"). Pass things as arguments to move them between scopes.

Comment: The difference between "environment" and "surroundings" is not clear for me, but your comment leads me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604346/does-python-scoping-rule-fits-the-definition-of-lexical-scoping, which cites this helpful definition of lexical scoping: "The body of a function is evaluated in the environment where the function is defined, not the environment where the function is called."

Comment: Regardless of other aspects, you have a circular import dependency going here.  B needs foobar which is defined in c. C imports b.  Not gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

`buzz` function's *definition* is in module "b.py". This means when the body of the `buzz` is being executed(`buzz()` in c.py), interpreter jumps into module `b`. Module `b`'s global namespace is where body of the `buzz` function can access global variables not `c`'s global namespace and of course there is no `"Foobar"` in module `b`'s `globals()`.

In LEGB rule, "G" points to the module's global namespace which the interpreter is currently in, not other modules' global namespace.