# Python logging with context

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging setup in python application that logs into file and MongoDB. The setup looks like this:

```
[logger_root]
handlers=myHandler,mongoHandler
level=DEBUG
qualname=myapp

[handler_myHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=myFormatter
args=('myapp.log', 'a',20000000,10)

[handler_mongoHandler]
class=myapp.MongoLogger.MongoLogger
level=INFO
args=('log',)

[formatter_myFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

And the MongoLogger has emit() function like this:

```
def emit(self, record):
    logdata = record.__dict__
    try:
        if(self.data == None):
            self.initDb()
        self.logtable.insert(logdata)
    except:
       self.handleError(record)
```

The logging is done like this then:

```
 logger.info("Processing account %s..." % account)
```

It works reasonably well, but now I have an additional requirement. I want it to have some context - i.e., to be able to define custom value - say, account name - so every log done inside the account processing would have the account name as part of the `record` passed to `emit` above and also available for the formatter in `myFormatter` string.

Is it possible to do this with logging module? Is there maybe another, better way to do the same?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can define a function inside the account processing code, after you get the account name, like this:

```
# account_name should already be defined
log = lambda msg: logger.info(msg, extra={'account': account_name})

###

log('Processing account...')
```

Note the `extra` keyword argument. It is used to add additional context to log records—in this case, the account name.

You can use context passed via `extra` in the formatter:

```
format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s - %(account)s'
```

Note that if you set up formatter like this and forget to pass `account`, you'll get a string formatting exception.

- [More information on `extra` keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

Comment: aha, missed that one - extra seems exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: Also LoggingAdapter helps to do what the lambda does, see here: http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info

Comment: Now that's what I didn't know about. Useful indeed.

Comment: Any idea how to do it nicely for all methods generating output (`error`, `critical`,...)?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Check out docs linked by StasM about LoggerAdapter: ‘This class is designed to look like a Logger, so that you can call debug(), info(), warning(), error(), exception(), critical() and log().’

Comment: Otherwise, you can conjure something like `log = lambda meth, msg: getattr(logger, meth)(msg, extra={'account': account_name})` and then call it like `log('debug', "Processing account")`, but this is not nice and I wouldn't recommend such style.

Answer (score 11):

### Explanation

Python official documentation ([logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output)) suggests two approaches to add contextual information to logs:

1. Using **LoggerAdapters** - for more details you can refer to [pete lin`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45609455/6812182).
2. Using **Filters** (and global context variables) -
   A filter processes the record before it is being emitted. It's main purpose is to allow advanced and customized rules to reject log records (the `filter` method returns bool, which indices whether to emit the record). However, it also allows you to process the record - and add attributes based on whatever is required. For example, you can set the attributes based on a global context, for which you have two options:

   1. [ContextVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) for python 3.7 and above (thanks to [jeromerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095024/jeromerg) for his comment)
   2. [threading.local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104983/what-is-thread-local-storage-in-python-and-why-do-i-need-it) variable for before python 3.7

**When to use what?**

1. I'd recommend **LoggerAdapters** if you need to edit records for specific looger *instances* - in which case, it makes sense to instantiate an Adapter instead.
2. I'd recommend **Filter** if you want to edit *all records* that are handled by a specific Handler - including other modules and 3rd party packages. It is generally a cleaner approach in my opinion, since we only configure our logger in our entry code - and the rest of the code remains the same (no need to replace logger instances with adapter instances).

### Code Example

Below is a `Filter` example that appends attributes from a global [threading.local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104983/what-is-thread-local-storage-in-python-and-why-do-i-need-it) variable:

*log_utils.py*

```
log_context_data = threading.local()


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information from `threading.local` (log_context_data) into the log.
    """
    def __init__(self, attributes: List[str]):
        super().__init__()
        self.attributes = attributes

    def filter(self, record):
        for a in self.attributes:
            setattr(record, a, getattr(log_context_data, a, 'default_value'))
        return True
```

And a ContextVar variant:

```
log_context_data = contextvars.ContextVar('log_context_data', default=dict())


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information from `contextvars.ContextVar` (log_context_data) into the log.
    """
    def __init__(self, attributes: List[str]):
        super().__init__()
        self.attributes = attributes

    def filter(self, record):
        context_dict = log_context_data.get()
        for a in self.attributes:
            setattr(record, a, context_dict.get(a, 'default_value'))
        return True
```

`log_context_data` can be set when you start processing an account, and reset when you you're done. However, I recommend setting it using a context manager:

Also in *log_utils.py* for either threading.local:

```
class SessionContext(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, context: dict = None):
        self.logger = logger
        self.context: dict = context

    def __enter__(self):
        for key, val in self.context.items():
            setattr(log_context_data, key, val)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, et, ev, tb):
        for key in self.context.keys():
            delattr(log_context_data, key)
```

Or ContextVar

```
class SessionContext(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, context: dict = None):
        self.logger = logger
        self.context: dict = context
        self.token = None

    def __enter__(self):
        context_dict = log_context_data.get()
        for key, val in self.context.items():
            context_dict[key] = val
        self.token = log_context_data.set(context_dict)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, et, ev, tb):
        log_context_data.reset(self.token)
        self.token = None
```

And a usage example, *my_script.py*:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = ...
handler.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter('{name}: {levelname} {account} - {message}', style='{'))
handler.addFilter(ContextFilter(['account']))
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
...
...
using SessionContext(logger=root_logger, context={'account': account}):
    ...
    ...
```

Notes:

1. `Filter` is only applied to the `logger` it is attached to. So if we attach it to a `logging.getLogger('foo')`, it won't affect `logging.getLogger('foo.bar')`. The solution is to attach the `Filter` to a `Handler`, rather than a `logger`.
2. `ContextFilter` could've rejected records, if `log_context_data` doesn't contain the required attribute. This depends on what you need.

Comment: You can consider using `ContextVar` instead of `threading.local()` to preserve the log context data across async calls

Answer (score 8):

Forgive the self promotion, but I have written a Python package called `log-with-context` that solves this problem. You can find it on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/log-with-context/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/neocrym/log-with-context/). Here is how to use `log-with-context` to log messages using an arbitrary number of thread-local context values.

### 1. Install `log-with-context` and a log formatter.

You have to pair `log-with-context` with a different logger that displays `extra` fields. My favorite log formatter is [JSON-log-formatter](https://pypi.org/project/JSON-log-formatter/).

You can install both packages with pip:

```sh
pip3 install log-with-context JSON-log-formatter
```

### 2. Configure the log formatter.

Here is how to configure `JSON-log-formatter` to print JSON logs of `INFO` and worse to standard error.

```py
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "json": {"()": "json_log_formatter.JSONFormatter"},
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "formatter": "json",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "INFO"},
    },
})
```

### 3. Create a new logger using `log-with-context`.

Then, here is how to create your logger:

```py
from log_with_context import add_logging_context, Logger

LOGGER = Logger(__name__)
```

### 4. Log messages using the `add_logging_context` context manager.

You can push and pop context keys and values using the `add_logging_context` context manager. Here is some example code to show how to use the context manager:

```py
with add_logging_context(current_request="hi"):
    LOGGER.info("Level 1")

    with add_logging_context(more_info="this"):
        LOGGER.warning("Level 2")

    LOGGER.info("Back to level 1")

LOGGER.error("No context at all...")
```

And this is what the above log messages look like when printed as JSON:

```json
{"current_request": "hi", "message": "Level 1", "time": "2021-08-03T21:29:45.987392"}
{"current_request": "hi", "more_info": "this", "message": "Level 2", "time": "2021-08-03T21:29:45.988786"}
{"current_request": "hi", "message": "Back to level 1", "time": "2021-08-03T21:29:45.989178"}
{"message": "No context at all...", "time": "2021-08-03T21:29:45.989600"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tony's answer just provide a function, but use `LoggerAdapter` we can get a context logger.

```
class ILoggerAdapter(LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, logger, extra):
        super(ILoggerAdapter, self).__init__(logger, extra)
        self.env = extra

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        msg, kwargs = super(ILoggerAdapter, self).process(msg, kwargs)

        result = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)

        default_kwargs_key = ['exc_info', 'stack_info', 'extra']
        custome_key = [k for k in result.keys() if k not in default_kwargs_key]
        result['extra'].update({k: result.pop(k) for k in custome_key})

        return msg, result
```

then just wrap your logger as

```
new_logger = ILoggerAdapter(old_logger, extra={'name': 'name'})

# new_logger is just same as old_logger    
# but can be pass to record
new_logger.info(msg='haha', id=100)

def emit(self, record):
    print(record.name)
    print(record.id)
```

Comment: If your kwargs have something that's not pickable it will fail.

Comment: I  don't understand the use of self.env = extra, as the attribute is used nowhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Handling class and give it some argument that contains the account name, although I'm not sure how that would work with the logging setup file.

Alternatively, the way I did this before was to add wrapper methods to call the logger methods.

So I would define:

```
class MyClass:
    account_name = "bob"
    def info(self, message):
        logging.info("%s|%s" % (self.account_name, message))
```

change the emit function to handle unpacking, and then call `self.info("Info message")` in place of `logger.info("Info message")`.

Comment: I am using ``logging.getLogger`` so I'd have to make it to create my class logger instead, and reimplement all logging methods. I was hoping for something more generic...