# Set/access local variable from a function in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to set a local variable in `main()` from `insideFCT()` which is starts in `main()`:

```
def insideFCT():
     print "inside"
     info = datetime.datetime.now()
     print info

def main():
     print "starting main"
     insideFCT()
     functionThatPrint(info) #for the example functionThatPrint() acts like print()

main()
```

I need to find a way so that it gives me:

```
starting main
inside
2013-09-19...
2013-09-19...
```

- I can't modify `main()` at all (it means I can't add "info = insideFCT()" and add a return to `insideFCT()`)
- I can't use global variables because the function is going to be use several times at the same time (threads)
- Of course this is not at all about getting the time, `datetime.datetime.now()` represents an input I can't control

My idea is to find something specific to each `main()` when they start, store "info" in a global dictionnary as `globDict[TheThingSpecific]=info` and then I can acces it using `globDict[TheThingSpecific]` in `functionThatPrint()` (Indeed, `functionThatPrint()` is called in the same function as `insideFCT()` so they have the same "specific thing")

I just found the "something specific" I was looking for. It's `threading.current_thread()`

**SOLUTION:**

- `insideFCT()` stores info into `globalDict[str(threading.current_thread())]`
- then  I can access it in `functionThatPrint()` using the same line because it's the same thread : `globalDict[str(threading.current_thread())]`

Comment: Why do you have these restrictions?

Comment: Why can't you pass info to the main method?

Comment: @alecxe it's part of my project, the first restriction is because main is going to be created by other people and i want it to be as simple as possible (even if "insideFCT" is a real mess). And the other ones I think I already explained it.

Comment: @Rami Helmy as I said I can't modify main() (I can add a return to insideFCT() on it's own it's useless)

Comment: the variable "info" is a local variable inside the function insideFCT.
To be able to access it from the second function "main", you should either declare it as global or pass it as a parameter to the second function. Unless there is something like a Friend function concept in Python like the Friend class in C++

Comment: Yes, I guess the last thing is what i'm looking for.

Comment: And just for my knowledge, is the opposite as difficult? (get a variable form main to functionThatPrint() without putting it in arguments?)

Comment: as a second thought, why don't you use the func_dict of the first function to store whatever variables you want, and then access it from the second function?

Comment: I just tried: it's a good idea but func_dict is the same for all my threads (i start them on the same python file) so it's pretty much the same as using global variables

Comment: An other way would be to find something specific to each function when it's starts so that i can store it in a global dictionnary and then get it in functionThatPrint.

Comment: @RamiHelmy `friend` is about access control, this one is about scope. the scope in python is lexical; there is no way to do it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set a local variable inside a function scope in python from outside. The scope to which the name `info` belongs is decided at "compile time" - that is, when the interpreter executes the `def main()` command.

Since the is no binding to `info` inside `main()`, it is assumed to be global or built-in. That's it.

Comment: May be but there are ways around it like my solution (even if it's not the cleanest thing ever)

Comment: So what you want is basically thrad-local storage?

Comment: Yes I didn't see it like that but you're right all I need is a way to make my thread communicate and have shared variables. With that it mind I look around and I think "Queue" is a good solution isn't it?

Comment: @user2707890 perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104983/what-is-thread-local-storage-in-python-and-why-do-i-need-it) may help.