# Add thread name to print statements in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, printing, python-multithreading

Is there a way to alter the print statement in Python to include the thread name before any printed message?

Currently my print statements look like

```py
print("[%s] Some text... " % self.name)
>> [thread_name] Some text...
```

I have a multithreaded web server where I track some behavior from each thread and it quickly gets tedious adding the above pattern to each print statement. Is there a quick way to redefine the `print()` function like this?

Comment: Perhaps by using `logging` instead of `print(...)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-from-multiple-threads

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643337/per-thread-logging-in-python

Comment: I assume you have a common class that you're instantiating for each thread? Or where exactly is `self.name` coming from?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, each thread is a class instance inheriting from `threading.Thread`, where I `self.name` them according to what they do.